# I want to sum up all the integers using js loop. In my given case correct answer is 6. How can i do this using Js?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

```
 <span class="gap">1</span>
 <span class="gap">2</span>
 <span class="gap">1</span>
 <span class="gap">2</span>`
```

```
var arr = []
var sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum += arr[i];
}
console.log(sum);
```

i was trying to do it by above code but i am unable to add all the integers in the array...

Comment: `arr` is empty. You need to sum up the values from the spans, not the array.

Comment: Or fill in the array first from the spans. Don't forget to convert the text to numbers, or you'll do concatenation rather than adding.

Comment: Yes i know i want to  add the int 1, 2, 1, 2 in `arr` using js

Comment: So what's stopping you? Use `document.querySelectorAll("span.gap")` to get all the spans. Loop over that, pushing the `textContent` into the array.

Comment: i am goint to add multiple integers hence i want a js loop to add the intergers in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you can use [`Document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) to get the matching `span`(s) then iterate those and call [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) like,

```js
var arr = document.getElementsByClassName("gap");
var sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  sum += parseInt(arr[i].textContent);
}
console.log(sum);
```

```html
 <span class="gap">1</span>
 <span class="gap">2</span>
 <span class="gap">1</span>
 <span class="gap">2</span>
```

Comment: *`document.getElementsByClassName()`, since JS is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

First you should extract the values from HTML.

Then you should convert them to numbers and sum.

I wrote this assuming there are no other elements having `class="gap"`; otherwise, you should write the parent element selector instead of `document`.

```
let gapsElements = document.querySelectorAll('.gap');
let sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < gapsElements.length; i++) {
    const gapValueInt = +gapsElements[i].innerText;  // the '+' before 'arr' will convert a string to number;
    sum += gapValueInt;  
}
console.log(sum);
```

I replaced prefixes to be more standart, and removed `array` var, as we don't need it.